# How are cmsmadesimple events sent?

Tags: php, events, cmsmadesimple

need help with cmsmadesimple events. I'm trying  handle modules FrontEndUsers event OnLogin. This module initiates this event in method.install.php:

```
$this->CreateEvent( 'OnLogin' );
```

In my Civicrm module method.instal.php  I register OnLogin handler:

```
$this->AddEventHandler( 'FrontEndUsers', 'OnLogin' );
```

So, lets start. FrontEndUser sends this event in action.do_login.php with:

```
$parms = array();
$parms['id'] = $this->LoggedInId();
$parms['username'] = $params['feu_input_username'];
$parms['ip'] = cge_utils::get_real_ip();
$this->SendEvent( 'OnLogin', $parms );
$this->_SendNotificationEmail('OnLogin',$parms);
```

I do in CiviCRM module:

```
public function DoEvent($originator, $eventname, &$params)
{
    if ($originator == 'FrontEndUsers' && $eventname == 'OnLogin')
        var_dump($params);
        die("feulogin");
    }
}
```

When you do front login, script is terminated as expected, but when trying to debug $params, got confused how event is send, because even commented out:

```
//$this->SendEvent( 'OnLogin', $parms );
```

DoEvent()handles event as well (exits script with message).

Couldnt find any more code in FrontEndUsers where OnLogin event is sent, so please help me find out that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. FrontEndUsers sends event from modules/FrontEndUsers/lib/class.FrontEndUsersManipulator.php:

```
function Login( $username, $password, $groups = '', $md5pw = false, $force_logout =false)
{
$module->SendEvent('OnLogin',array('id'=>$uid,'username'=>$username,'ip'=>$ip));
}
```